# Small Business SIP Fail over multiple ISP's

Tags: cisco, sonicwall, failover, sip

Currently using a sonicwall but looking... small organization but calls are important.

Is there a way to do a failover between two different ISP's and NOT have the sip traffic drop.  We use a Internet based VoIP provider, we have no onprem equipment.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In a word: NO.

Your IP address changes when you change ISPs. So any calls currently active on the now-down-ISP will fail. (there may be some trickery that could get the call(s) to redirect/forward to a new SIP endpoint, but I don't think that can work with the current endpoint unreachable.)

If you have a tunnel to your internet voip provider, then yes, you could rearrange the underlying transport all you want -- the endpoints aren't changing, so the calls will stay up. (failover *quickly*)

Comment: Actually if he had either PI or a portable address block it's possible to leverage it to keep the SIP destination constant between providers

Comment: True, but the words he uses makes me suspect he doesn't even have static addresses, much less a globally routable block.